# AndroidHttpClient. How do I set KeepAlive strategy?

Tags: android

What would be syntax to do that. It's not DefaultHttpClient, it's AndroidHttpClient.

I noticed some exceptions with broken pipes and I want to set connections to keep alive for 10-20 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
httpParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, <Timeout in milliseconds>);
```